# Running submit-api on mac for Nami to connect to Daedalus?

Tags: cardano-node

I found windows-based [instructions](https://cardanode.com.au/reducing-transaction-connecting-nami-to-daedalus/) for this, and looking to do it on mac. Problem is I know nothing about Windows Powershell.

Could someone help translate the following, suitable for mac terminal?

```
$ENV:CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH = (Get-ChildItem \\.\pipe\ | Where-Object {$_.name -like "cardano-node*"}).FullName

Run this to check to see if the command worked.
$ENV:CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH

You should see something like
\.\pipe\cardano-node-mainnet.12768.1

Now execute the next command to start the Cardano Submit API
.\cardano-submit-api.exe --mainnet --socket-path $ENV:CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH --config .\tx-submit-mainnet-config.yaml --port 8090

You should see
Running server on 127.0.0.1:8090
```

To clarify from the above, if I export an env var, what should 'something here' be on mac/linux?
`export CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH='something here'`

As for the command to execute, I think it should just be:

`.\cardano-submit-api --mainnet --socketpath CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH --config tx-submit-mainnet-config.yaml --port 8090`

Only bit I'm stuck with is what the actual env var is or how it is being set above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TD;DR**

Full instructions for Mac/linux are here: https://pastebin.com/MbjkvgL5

Regarding permissions running unverified applications: https://www.lifewire.com/fix-developer-cannot-be-verified-error-5183898

---

**Long version**

Found it going to this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sfLhNEtiktA

Under one of the comments was a link to this twitter post:
https://twitter.com/877PSBYTE6/status/1485438232254812163

Which referenced this manual:
https://pastebin.com/MbjkvgL5

**Important note**

I had to allow about 7-10 lib files which were not allowed by the mac’s default security policy.
Did this by opening “Security & Privacy” in “System Preferences”.
This helped to go through the security: https://www.lifewire.com/fix-developer-cannot-be-verified-error-5183898